# Delete all data in mongoDB at once from React with API axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api, axios

I'm new at programming, and need some help.
In React I'm trying to delete all items from database mongoDB with axios using map(). When I click button "Delete", it removes only one first item on click. But I need to remove all items at once.

```
deleteAllHaspInfo = (e) => {     
     if (confirm("Do you really want to delete all hasp information from database?") === true){  //eslint-disable-line
          axios.delete("/hasp/delete", {
            data: {
              _id: this.state.hasps.map((_id) => _id)
            }
           })
           .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
           })
           .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
         })
   } else {
     alert("Delete Canceled!");
   }       
   }
```

```
<button className="btn btn-danger" style={{margin:'0 10px'}}
          onClick={this.deleteAllHaspInfo}>Delete all hasp info from database</button>
```

It needs to delete all items at once. I think that I'm using map() wrong...

Comment: Can you share your MongoDB query?

Comment: Try using mongodb query:- 
db.collection.deleteMany({"_id" : { $in : [ArrayOfIds]} })

Comment: `//DELETE request
app.delete("/hasp/delete", function(req, res) {
 HaspInfo.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.body._id}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
   res.status(500).send({error: "No such hasp id in database..."});   
  } else {
   res.status(200).send({message: "Hasp deleted succesfully..."});
  }
 });
});`

Comment: this is my current delete request to mongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, it worked for me when I used on Server query deleteMany to mongoDB:

```
 //DELETE ALL FROM DB request
app.delete("/hasp/deleteAll", function(req, res) {
    HaspInfo.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({error: "Could not clead database..."});           
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({message: "All hasp info was deleted succesfully..."});
        }
    });
});
```

And on React client I changed request to this:

```
axios.delete("/hasp/deleteAll", {data: {}})
```